# How do I simplify $\overline{X}\overline{Y} + YZ + \overline{X}Y\overline{Z}$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

$$\overline{X}\overline{Y} + YZ + \overline{X}Y\overline{Z}$$

I'm having a lot of trouble simplifying this boolean expression.

I used commutative property and re-arranged it as my first step:
$$\overline{X}Y\overline{Z} + \overline{X}\overline{Y} + YZ$$
2nd Step: Factored out the common literal, $\overline{X}$.
$$\overline{X}(\overline{Y} + Y\overline{Z}) + YZ$$
3rd Step: ? I first used one of the identities to turn $\overline{Y} + Y$ into 1; I wasn't too sure what to do here and I believed what I did was wrong, so I then used the distributive property for the sum term in the parentheses instead. But, I don't know if this aforementioned step is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{X}\overline{Y}+YZ+\overline{X}Y\overline{Z}=$

$\overline{X}\overline{Y}+\color{blue}{YZ}+\overline{X}Y\overline{Z}=$

$=\overline{X}\overline{Y}+\color{blue}{YZ\left(1+\overline{X}\right)}+\overline{X}Y\overline{Z}=$

$=\overline{X}\overline{Y}+YZ+\overline{X}YZ+\overline{X}Y\overline{Z}=$

$=\overline{X}\overline{Y}+YZ+\overline{X}Y\left(Z+\overline{Z}\right)=$

$=\overline{X}\overline{Y}+YZ+\overline{X}Y=$

$=\overline{X}\left(\overline{Y}+Y\right)+YZ=$

$=\overline{X}+YZ$

**More details about the steps:**

$\color{blue}{YZ=YZ\cdot1=YZ\left(1+\overline{X}\right)}$

because $\;1+\overline{X}=1\;$ whatever is the value of $\;X\;,$

indeed, if $\;X=0\;,\;$ then $\;1+\overline{X}=1+1=1\;,$

whereas if $\;X=1\;,\;$ then $\;1+\overline{X}=1+0=1\;.$

Comment: Your first step doesn't make sense. As a counterexample, let $X=0, Y=Z=1$. Your final expression is $0$ whereas the original expression is $1$. The actual final answer should be $\overline{X} + XYZ$.

Comment: If $X=0,Y=Z=1$, my final expression is $1$, not $0$, moreover $\overline{X}+XYZ=\overline{X}+YZ$ is true in any case. My first step is correct because $1+A=1$ for any boolean variable A.

Comment: Hm, I was interpreting $+$ as xor, whereas you're interpreting it as or. Is this a standard convention? I'm used to boolean algebra being modeled on arithmetic in the field with two elements, which uses xor for addition.

Comment: Usually in boolean algebra the symbol of ‘xor’ is ‘$⊕$’, whereas the symbol of ‘or’ is ‘$+$’. Boolean algebra is not the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. If you use ‘$+$’ for ‘xor’, which symbol will you use for ‘or’? ‘$\lor$‘? Usually it is not so.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson, if you have any doubt, why do not you ask the original poster what he means with the symbol ‘$+$’?

Comment: Angelo is correct: ⊕ is XOR. I've seen people on YouTube introduce new terms to simplify Boolean expressions, but I didn't understand how I would use that to my advantage. If this answer had more details about the steps taken, I would approve of it. I also want to know if my way of doing it would yield a correct answer?

Comment: @S.Coughing, do you need more details? Look at my answer now. I think your way would not yield a correct answer because the final expression you get, could be simplified further.

Comment: It's all good, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, apologies for the digression.